# .replaceWith() is not working in jQuery 1.9+

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, replacewith, jquery-2.0

I'm trying to clone a `<textarea>` and clone and replace the digit in the label `<label> Number 1 <label>` increasing by 1 each time the add button is pressed (So the first label will have Number 1, the label underneath Number 2 etc).

This works with jQuery 1.8 and below but anything above does not clone and add 1 to the digit.

HTML

```
<div>
 <label for="number">Number <span class="one">1</span></label>
 <textarea id="number"></textarea>
</div>
<button>Add</button>
```

jQuery

```
var $row = $('div').clone(),
    cloneCount = 2;

$('button').click(function () {
    $row.clone().insertBefore($("button"));
    $('span').clone().attr('span', cloneCount++).replaceWith($('[class=one]:last')).text(cloneCount - 1);
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wba6jvkj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you were attempting with `.attr('span'` and why it seemed to work in < 1.8, or why you are subtracting one from `cloneCount`, but this should do what you want:

```
var $row = $('div').clone(),
    cloneCount = 2;

$('button').click(function () {
    $row.clone().insertBefore($("button"));
    $('span.one:last').text(cloneCount++);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wba6jvkj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

(Answering to this old question, as Google led me here.)

The behavior of `.replacewith()` with disconnected nodes has been modified in jQuery 1.9. You may find the following explanation in the [replaceWith() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) (section "Additional Notes"), and also [in the jQuery 1.9 upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#after-before-and-replacewith-with-disconnected-nodes):

> Prior to jQuery 1.9, `.replaceWith()` would attempt to add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the set was not connected to a document, and in those cases return a new jQuery set rather than the original set. The method might or might not have returned a new result depending on the number or connectedness of its arguments! As of jQuery 1.9, `.after()`, `.before()`, and `.replaceWith()` always return the original unmodified set. Attempting to use these methods on a node without a parent has no effect—that is, neither the set nor the nodes it contains are changed.

In your code, you are using `.replaceWith()` on a cloned element, thus which hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet.